# How to show facebook like button, only if page isn't liked yet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

Is there any way to hide the like button if my page is already liked?

I want to suggest liking my page, but only for the user whom haven't liked yet.

I tryed: https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes
and
Searching for content with jQuery,

But neither of them seems to grant me a usable solution.

Comment: There is not, and you are not supposed to do that in the first place, Facebook does not want you to. Plus, it is of course only common decency that you would let me unlike something in the same place where I liked it, for example if I clicked by mistake.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I understand the mindset behind it. The thing is: we have **two places** to like. One on the top, and one suggestion at the bottom. And the suggestion maybe seems strange/assertive if someone has already liked it. So we thought maybe we could remove it. Anyways, Thank you @CBroe for your help :)

Comment: you can do it by managing some extra entity in your database.

Comment: @NegiRox like saving who pressed what by, ip? But what about non-static ip-s, and users who have been liking the page in the past. :) It really seems like there is no reliable solution.

Comment: At most you could subscribe to the event of someone liking/unliking your page via those buttons, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.12 But of course that won’t help you, when a visitor like/unlikes the page in some other place.

Comment: gotcha your point